# Excel Macro VBA for loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I have three sets of data:

first set of data in Cell "D2" to "F107" in "Sheet1"
second set of data in Cell "G2" to "G572" in "Sheet2"
third set of data in Cell  "I2" to "I572" in "Sheet2"

can anyone please help for the VBA coding if I want to perform the actions below:

by using each data in the first set to search within the second set of data, if found a contain, return to the third set of data value

for example:

if VBA finds a contain of Cell "E19" in "Sheet1" in the Cell "G200" in "Sheet2", then it returns Cell "I200" in "Sheet2"

thank you

Comment: [How to use the LOOKUP function in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324986/en-us)

Comment: or [Index + Match](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/)

Comment: Hello I am Excel Marco :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim i As string
Dim j As string
Dim k As string

For i = 2 To 107
    For j = 4 To 6
        For k = 2 To 573
            If Sheet1.Cells(i, j) = Sheet2.Cells(k, 7) Then
                sheet3.Cells(k, 9) ' you code
            End If
        Next k
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: but my lookup variables in sheet1 is string, and the the indexing array in sheet2 is also a set of string,  they may not be exactly match, so the equal sign still works?

Comment: Then change your variables to string, like I just did. What do you mean they may not be exact match? Then how are  you going to compare them?

Comment: yes, InStr(string1, string2) will return the first instance of string2 it finds in string1.